# Add user input number to activcell value

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

I want to ask the user for a number, add that number to the value in the active cell, then place the result in a cell that is three rows up and two columns right of the active cell.

```vb
Sub AddNumbersB()
    Dim x As Double
    x = InputBox("Please enter a number")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 2).Value = x
```

Comment: You forgot the line `x = x + ActiveCell.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add that number `x` to the value of `ActiveCell`. Right now you just write the value `x` so change:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 2).Value = ActiveCell.Value + x
```

---

If you would make this a solid procedure you would do something like the following:

1. Check if you can move 3 up and 2 right from the `ActiveCell`. If that's not possible we need to choose another cell first.
2. Make sure you use the [Application.InputBox method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) where you can specify a `Type:=1` so this box only accepts numbers. Note `Application.InputBox` is different from `InputBox` (which does not allow types).
   Also make sure to define the return value as `Variant` because the Application.InputBox method will either return a number or return `False` as `Boolean` in case of cancel.
3. Then check if the user pressed the <kbd>cancel</kbd> button (so it doesn't perform the calculation and exits instead).
   The Application.InputBox method will return a `False` of type `Boolean` on cancel. Why can't we just check for `RetVal = False` to identify the cancel? Because if the user enters `0` as a number this will be treated as cancel aswell because `False` and `0` is considered to be equal in VBA. Therfore we need to check if the type is `Boolean` too!
4. Finally if all conditions are met and the user entered a number and pressed <kbd>OK</kbd> we can perform the addition and write the result.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddNumbersB()
    ' check if active cell can move 3 up and 2 right
    If ActiveCell.Row > 3 And ActiveCell.Column < ActiveSheet.Columns.Count - 2 Then
        Dim RetVal As Variant
        RetVal = Application.InputBox("Please enter a number", Type:=1) 'Type 1 only allows to input numbers
        
        ' check if user pressed cancel and exit
        If VarType(RetVal) = vbBoolean And RetVal = False Then Exit Sub
        
        ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 2).Value = ActiveCell.Value + RetVal
    Else
        MsgBox "Can't move 3 up or 2 right. Choose another cell where this is possible."
    End If
End Sub
```